# Connected apps available via Metadata API?

Tags: managed-package, metadata, metadata-api, appexchange, connected-apps

When developing apps for the AppExchange, we use a development workflow in which each developer has their own DE org, but commits to a common source code repository (git in this case).  We then use a continuous integration tool (Bamboo) to pull code from the repo into a common org from which we declare the namespace and create the managed package (the "packaging org").  (See http://www.soliantconsulting.com/blog/2013/03/salesforcecomforcecom-team-development).

The problem I've encountered today is that I need to create a "Connected App" in my dev org, but it does not appear that I can "fetch" it out of my DE org using the Metadata API in order to add it to the repo and eventually to push it to the "packaging" org for inclusion in the managed package.

Is this workflow possible for Connected Apps?  Or do I need to create the Connected App directly in the packaging org, in which case I would (a) not be able to save the Connected App metadata in the repo and (b) violate our rule that we do not do any development work in the packaging org itself.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It appears there is something special about the meta data for a Connected App.

I have one in my Dev org, but I can't add it to an unmanaged package. 
[image: Connected App does not appear in unmanaged package]

However, in a managed package the "Connected App" Component Type appears.
[image: Connected App appears in Managed Package]

Based on the managed package component type select options I'd expect the Metadata component to be "ConnectedApplication2".
[image: Package Component Types]

As you found, I can't see this metadata type using workbench against the same Org (API v28).
[image: Workbench for ConnectedApplication2]

So, without the benefit of internal Salesforce knowledge, I'd conclude that you can't currently get the metadata for a Connected App outside of a managed package.

Comment: Fantastic answer, Daniel.  Thanks for confirming and for going the extra mile to throw these screenshots in here.  Should be useful for others as they encounter the same thing.  @metadaddy is checking for us whether or not there are plans to add Connected Apps to the Metadata API.  See [this tweet](https://twitter.com/metadaddy/status/369622629079982081).

Comment: From SF Sys Engineer @cmort: ["metadata API for Connected Apps ( SAML, OAuth, OpenID Connect, and Canvas ) this fall."](https://twitter.com/cmort/status/369838890732892161)

Comment: This issue is preventing us from being able to adjust connected app OAuth Policies / OAuthConfigs via MetadataService API.  See [this post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/286527/is-it-possible-to-programmatically-change-connectedapp-settings-in-production) and [this answer to a different post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/294976/55891) for some unfortunate consequences of this limitation

Answer (score 3):

It's part of v29.0 - http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_connectedapp.htm, is available in sandbox environment as on today as preview and would be GAed in couple of months from now.