# Metadata API Apex fails to create fields in Connected App

Tags: apex, metadata-api, connected-apps, saml, certificates

I am using the latest v46 version of the Financial Force Metadata API Apex Wrapper to create a Connected App but the values I put in the code are partly ignored.

What is not working:

1. `ConnectedApp.permissionSetName` (perm sets are in Managed Package)
2. Set `ConnectedAppOauthConfig.isAdminApproved = true`

All expected Metadata objects are created with no errors.

```
   public override PageReference run() {
    createConnectedApp();
    createSamlSsoConfig();

    return refresh();
}


// PRIVATE

private void createConnectedApp() {
    if(connectedApp.isEmpty() || Test.isRunningTest()) {
        MetadataService.ConnectedApp app = new MetadataService.ConnectedApp();
        app.fullName = SetupCtrl.DEV_NAME;
        app.label = SetupCtrl.DEV_NAME;
        app.contactEmail = UserInfo.getUserEmail();
        app.oauthConfig = oauthConfig();
        app.permissionSetName = new List<String>{ 'PackagedAdminPermSet' };// WONT WORK

        save(new List<MetadataService.Metadata>{ app });
    }
}

private MetadataService.ConnectedAppOauthConfig oauthConfig() {
    MetadataService.ConnectedAppOauthConfig result = new MetadataService.ConnectedAppOauthConfig();
    result.isAdminApproved = true; // WONT WORK
    result.callbackUrl = 'http://localhost/callback';
    result.scopes = new List<String>{ 'Api', 'Web', 'RefreshToken', 'OpenID' };

    return result;
}
```

Comment: There have been issues with managing connected apps via Metadata API. Last we tried it they weren't resolved but perhaps someone else has succeeded.

Comment: Is that publicly documented somewhere or do you know a Salesforce pm who is responsible for this?

Comment: Not aware of any KIs and they might have been resolved, it's tough to tell from the outside. The PMs read the [Identity group on Trailblazer](https://success.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?g=0F9300000001q1N), post there and hopefully they'll respond.

Comment: Have you also heard from the specific problem that I have here?

Comment: Not specifically identical to yours, no.

Comment: I tried to retrieve metadata for the connected app using my IDE, it did not retrieve `Idp certificate`

Comment: Wondering about that 'encryptionCertificate' assignment, the [doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_connectedapp.htm) says 'The **name** of the certificate...'

Comment: `permissionSetName` should be set to a `String` and not a `List<String>` according to the [ConnectedApp](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_connectedapp.htm) metadata type doc

Comment: @BrianMiller did you try that and how do you make it work with multiple perm sets?

Comment: @RobertSösemann No I didn't try it. Been dragging my feet to try something like this in light of your post here as well as Robert Hyatt's post [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/286527/is-it-possible-to-programmatically-change-connectedapp-settings-in-production?noredirect=1#comment438767_286527). What you're trying to achieve is exactly the issue I'm hitting with our managed package as well :-/

Comment: @RobertSösemann Was able to achieve part 1 through Permission Sets and `SetupEntityAccess`. See my comment on Clint's answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Re 1

In order to get the `ConnectedApp.permissionSetName` set, you can use `SetupEntityAccess` and regular DML commands to associate a connected app with a permission set.  Only caveat - you can't adjust a managed permission set, so you'll have to create your own new permission set.

Code Sample:

```
//== (1) Create new permission set ==//
PermissionSet connectedPs = new PermissionSet(
    Label='Connected App User',
    Name='Connected_App_User',
    Description='Gives permissions to use the managed connected app'
);

insert connectedPs;

// Get Managed Connected App
ConnectedApplication myApp = [SELECT Id, Name, OptionsAllowAdminApprovedUsersOnly FROM ConnectedApplication WHERE Name like 'MyManagedAppName' LIMIT 1];

//== (2) Associate the new perm set with the connected app ==//
SetupEntityAccess sea = new SetupEntityAccess(
    ParentId = connectedPs.Id,
    SetupEntityId = app.Id
);

upsert seas;
```

#### Re 2

You can't set `isAdminApproved` via MetadataService API classes because you literally can't read the managed package via the `readMetadata()` method.  As per my comment on the question in [this post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/286527/is-it-possible-to-programmatically-change-connectedapp-settings-in-production?noredirect=1&lq=1)

> I was able to configure and do a `readMetadata` on `isAdminApproved` within the packaging org itself, but then ran into the same issue in production - `readMetadata` doesn't return managed connected apps results, and interestingly enough, workbench also doesn't show managed connected apps (as mentioned in the `retrieveConnectedApp()` method in the [MetadataServicesExamples](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi/blob/master/apex-mdapi/src/classes/MetadataServiceExamples.cls) file (line 1517 at time of posting). I don't know if this is a deficiency in Metadata API or not

So it seems this will be a manual step that's unavoidable for Production environments.

---

Regardless, here's the script that I ran that would work in non-production environments but didn't run correctly in a production environment, because, again, `readMetadata` just wouldn't retrieve managed packages :-/

*Note*: I had to update a few extra properties (like `isAdminApproved` and `permissionSetName`) within [MetadataService](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi/blob/master/apex-mdapi/src/classes/MetadataService.cls) in order to properly read and set these properties.  Also needed to update the version to 47 or later.

See all the changes to `MetadataService` that I made [in this gist](https://gist.github.com/brianevanmiller/a94120b10b2d3c2f04be4bb29b2587b1).  Simply search for `BMiller` and you'll see all the places that I modified code.

Below is the script using the modified version of `MetadataService`

```
// Modified and taken from MetadataServicesExamples
MetadataService.MetadataPort service = new MetadataService.MetadataPort();
service.SessionHeader = new MetadataService.SessionHeader_element();
service.SessionHeader.sessionId = UserInfo.getSessionId();
String appFullName = 'myNamespace__My_Connected_App';
MetadataService.ConnectedApp connectedApp =
    (MetadataService.ConnectedApp)service.readMetadata('ConnectedApp', new String[] {appFullName}).getRecords()[0];

System.debug('connectedApp = ' + connectedApp);
System.debug(connectedApp.oauthConfig.isAdminApproved);
System.debug(connectedApp.permissionSetName);
System.debug(connectedApp.description);

// Attempting to set the isAdminApproved setting.
connectedApp.oauthConfig.isAdminApproved = true;

// Works in non-production environments.  In production environments, connectedApp is showing up null
List<MetadataService.UpsertResult> results =
    service.upsertMetadata(new MetadataService.Metadata[] { connectedApp });

MetadataService.UpsertResult upsertResult = results[0];
if(upsertResult.errors!=null) {
    List<String> messages = new List<String>();
    messages.add(
        (upsertResult.errors.size()==1 ? 'Error ' : 'Errors ') +
        'occured processing component ' + upsertResult.fullName + '.');
    for(MetadataService.Error error : upsertResult.errors)
        messages.add(
            error.message + ' (' + error.statusCode + ').' +
            ( error.fields!=null && error.fields.size()>0 ?
             ' Fields ' + String.join(error.fields, ',') + '.' : '' ) );
    if(messages.size()>0)
        System.debug(String.join(messages, ' '));
}
if(!upsertResult.success)
    System.debug('Request failed with no specified error.');
```

Comment: Would it be possible to create a local clone of the packaged permission set? In Apex. Did you try that?

Comment: @RobertSösemann Just searched around and didn't fine anything out of the box in Apex.  Do you want to post as a question or should I?  :-)

Comment: Hey Brian, I created this here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/295652/256 Maybe someone can add the missing piece here.

Answer (score 6):

I think the second problem you listed is causing the first problem, and unfortunately it's a bit of a layered answer. I'm also assuming that the MetadataService layer you've generated is all correct.

The first part to solve is getting the `ConnectedAppOauthConfig.isAdminApproved = true`. Now I couldn't get this to set on creation of the Connected App. However, when I update the Connected App just created with the setting of `ConnectedAppOauthConfig.isAdminApproved = true` it sticks. So you will need to create the Connected App first then update the same app to make the setting stick.

Now going back to the [Connected App documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_connectedapp.htm), the 'permissionSetName' field requires the 'isAdminApproved' to be set to true so we can't set the permission sets on create. I was able to set unmanaged permission sets on the update, but got the following error when trying to set the managed package permission set:

> Cannot modify managed object: entity=SetupEntityAccess, component=0J0O000000Ceu83, field=KeyPrefix, state=installed

The [ConnectedAppPlugin class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Auth_ConnectedAppPlugin.htm) might be something you will need to explore as an authorisation alternative if you don't have control of the managed package setup.

Comment: I will grant the bounty to you and it would be nice if you take some time to find answers later.

Comment: I added my full code and a list of what is not working so you see what I am doing. I think I am not missing required stuff as everything gets created. At least all Metadata objects are there.

Comment: Hoping I got it now :D thank you for sharing that additional context as it definitely helps

Comment: I created my own MetadataService from the v46 WSDL, so thats not relevant. Would be great if you could try it with code and post that. Especially the linking of packaged perm sets is a mystery.

Comment: Ahh bugger! Can you please share the code snippet for the OAuthConfig class to help round out the question for completeness? I'll need to try it with code tomorrow. Based on the documentation we will need to get the 'isAdminApproved' working first which is why I'm interested in the MetadataService you generated.

Comment: Its in the code. Please check again

Comment: Apologies I meant the MetadataService layer as yes I can read what you wrote haha I'm updating my answer now anyway to show what I've uncovered

Comment: @RobertSösemann and Clint - worth noting that I was able to create a `PermissionSet`, leverage `SetupEntityAccess` to connect the permission set to the managed package connected app, then use `PermissionSetAssignment` to auto-assign to active users, all within a post-install script. Still need to enable the `isAdminApproved` oauth setting through the UI (tried via `MetadataService` but doesn't read/write managed connected apps in Production orgs...), but the connected app will be properly associated to the new PS and users. One less step :-)

Comment: @BrianMiller its great that you could solve it but your short comment doesn't help me to solve. It only partly can find the Metadata objects PermissionSet, PermissionSetAssignment and SetupEntityAccess in the MDAPI docu from Salesforce. I also dont have them in my version of Financial Forces MetadataService. Could you share a full code example in a GIST. I would grant 200 reputation points.

Comment: @RobertSösemann Sorry running into a hectic week but would love to post.  BTW, those three objects have nothing to do with MDAPI - they're all standard objects in Salesforce and can be simply created and updated like any other standard/custom object via regular `insert` `update` `upsert` DML commands

Comment: For what it's worth I use the [Salesforce inspector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/salesforce-inspector/aodjmnfhjibkcdimpodiifdjnnncaafh?hl=en) chrome extension to search and see object fields & relationships, and use the Data Export button to do some quick queries (it has autocomplete and shows the complete list of fields once you've filled in the object of interest). Huge time saver and very insightful for me

Comment: @BrianMiller I also made it work for both issues. But only for a newly created permset which only grants access to the connectedapp. But what about my packaged admin permset. Can I recreate it by cloning? Or what does a connapp actually need?

Comment: @RobertSösemann Right now I just have the post-install script creating a new permset, granting access to the connected app and applying it to all active users.  So I apply the managed package permset as well as this newly created one - so we have two permsets at the end of the day.  If I knew this from the beginning, I might have just designed it to have the post-install just create a permset with every permission I needed and leave it separate from the managed package itself, so that I would only need that permset

Comment: @RobertSösemann You said you made it work for both issues - you got `isAdminApproved` setting itself in a production environment? That's where I hit a wall.  Re posting code - looking to do it over the weekend

Comment: @BrianMiller how did you set isAdminApproved which worked in Dev but not in Prod? I couldn't yet test it. Would you mind starting with an answer so I can grant you the bounty for help. Only 1 day left!