# Clone packaged permission set in Apex

Tags: apex, managed-package, connected-apps, permission-sets, isv

As part of [another question where I tried to automate the creation of a Connected App](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/271632/256) for a Managed App and were successful with many steps but failed

- Assign a packaged permission set to the `Connected App`
- Set the Connected App's Oauth to `Is Admin Auto-Approved`

It worked in a Developer org but not in a production org setting.

I know that I am able to manually clone the Packaged Permission Set and do those 2 steps manually but maybe there is also a way to do this cloning from Apex.

Is it possible (and how) to create a Permission Set copy for a managed package Permission Set? This should also work in subscriber Production Orgs.

Comment: I'm guessing triggering an outside API to do this is out of the question?

Comment: Is it something like Metadata or tooling api? Then it’s ok but not my own java service on Heroku.

Comment: Salesforce SFDX CLI will do a lot, and can be augmented with Puppeteer. Host your own Deployment As A Service 

Answer (score 1):

Cloning permission set is not a problem at all.

```
PermissionSet ps = [SELECT Fields(Standard) FROM PermissionSet WHERE Name = 'PermissionName' AND NamespacePrefix = 'Namespace'];
ps.clone(false);
ps.Id = null;
insert ps;
```

And you can use SetupEntityAccess to assign a permission set to a connected app.

```
SetupEntityAccess sea = new SetupEntityAccess(
    ParentId = ps.Id,
    SetupEntityId = app.Id
);

upsert sea;
```