# Go to Managed Connected App's manage permissions page via URL

Tags: managed-package, connected-apps, urlhacking

I'm trying to create a setup page for a managed package, whereby you can click a link/button and be taken directly to the connected app manage settings page.

That would show them their current settings and then allow them to use the `Edit Policies` to adjust their OAuth Policy settings both on `Permitted Users` and `IP Relaxation`.

I'm trying to do a bit of a hack from the page's URL:

`https://myDevOrg-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/lightning/setup/ConnectedApp/page?address=%2F_ui%2Fcore%2Fapplication%2Fforce%2Fconnectedapp%2FForceConnectedApplicationPage%2Fd%3FapplicationId%3D06P1U000000cnDe`

1. I'm having trouble making sense of the URL and what elements I really need
2. I cannot figure out what `applicationId` refers to.  I would think that's the Connected App itself, but those start with `0H4` and this begins with `06P`.

If I can query this applicationId somehow, then I can dynamically create a similar link on a subscriber's org.

**Question**: how do I build a link that will direct subscribing users to the actual connected app manage settings page?

**Bonus**: what would the Edit Policies page URL link look like?

---

*Extra Context*: I tried adjusting these via Apex code, but doesn't seem possible in a production environment (see [this post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/286527/is-it-possible-to-programmatically-change-connectedapp-settings-in-production#comment442096_286527) and [an extended answer on another post in the Re 2 section](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/271632/metadata-api-apex-fails-to-create-fields-in-connected-app/294976#294976) if this is applicable to you)